# (Javascript) : Iframe loadable only on domain, else redirect the whole page

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect, iframe, source-code-protection

There is a site that I know of, that does something interesting to half protect its source code and I'd like to understand how.

Basically :

They made 3 pages named A, B and C.

1. A contains all the data and stuff : loads in B.
2. B is blank : displays A full page.
3. C is the main page : Where you end up if you try to load A from your browser.

How do they do that ?

The interesting part is that the source code only shows the iframe in body, and shows no data (even if there is in A)..

But it's still visible from the console after it loaded though..

Thanks !

Comment: _“How do they do that ?”_ - I would rather ask _why_, because that seems a pretty idiotic thing to do, and is bad for usability. // If you really still think that your client-side code could be “protected” in any way, then I’d say you have not done proper research on this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without page A code, but I guess there is javascript or jquery script in page A that looks for knowing if there is a parent, if not script makes redirection to page C.